# How to implement session tokens in google maps autocomplete javascript API

Tags: javascript, autocomplete

i am trying to implement autocomplete google maps javascript API (trying to display autocomplete text box without displaying maps). Its working fine but the API request count is increasing for every key pressed. google says to implement sessions token parameter so that only 1 request is counted when i select item from the list. Can anyone please guide me as to where and how to implement session token? I am attaching my full code below :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
   <link rel="stylesheet" 
    href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter- 
    bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"> 
   </script>
   <title>Google Places Autocomplete InputBox Example Without Showing Map - 
   </title>
    <style>
    .container{
    padding: 10%;
    text-align: center;
    } 
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12"><h2>Google Places Autocomplete InputBox Example 
    Without Showing Map</h2></div>
        <div class="col-12">
            <div id="custom-search-input">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input id="autocomplete_search" 
    name="autocomplete_search" type="text" class="form-control" 
    placeholder="Search" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="lat">
                    <input type="hidden" name="long">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>


    <script type="text/javascript" 
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js? 
    key=MYAPIKEY&sessionToken=Token&libraries=places"></script>

    <script>
     google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    function initialize() {
      var Token = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteSessionToken(); 
      var input = document.getElementById('autocomplete_search');

      var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
      autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function () {
       var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
      // place variable will have all the information you are looking for.
      // $('#lat').val(place.geometry['location'].lat());
      // $('#long').val(place.geometry['location'].lng());
     });
      }
    </script>`enter code here`



    </html>
```